# If $r^{n-r}=k^{n-k}$, when is this true other than $r=k$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $n,r,k$ be non negative integers such that $r,k\leq n$.

If $r^{n-r}=k^{n-k}$, when is this true other than $r=k$ ?

For example it is holds for $n=6,r=2,k=4$.

Comment: @Shakespeare I am a bit surprised by your commment... Take $r=11$, $k=17$ and $n=18$...

Comment: @Worachead, I am a bit confused, when you set r and k to be different(in your example you set them to be 6 and 4 respectively), how can you make them be equal?!

Comment: @jaseem I think the question is: what are the conditions for which if $r^{n-k}=k^{n-k}$, then $r=k$? Of course he states that this is not a general rule, since the case $n=6$, $r=2$ and $k=4$ is a clear case.

Comment: My question is: what are the conditions for which if $r^{n−r}=k^{n−k}$, then $r=k$?

Comment: @jaseem if $n=6,r=2,k=4$,then the condition $r^{n-r}=2^{6-2}=2^4=16=4^2=4^{6-4}=k^{n-k}$ is true while $r\neq k$.

Answer (score 4):

This equation has many solutions. I have no general form to find all these solutions, but if you're just interested in finding some other values for which it holds, you can do the following:
$$r^{n-r} = k^{n-k} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad 1=\frac{k^{n-k}}{r^{n-r}}=\left(\frac{k}{r}\right)^{n-r}k^{r-k} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad k^{k-r}=\left(\frac{k}{r}\right)^{n-r}.$$
This leads to an expression for $n$, depending on $r$ and $k$:
$$n=r+\frac{\ln{k}}{\ln{k}-\ln{r}}(k-r).$$
You can choose any $r$ and $k$ and the equation will give you $n$. You can make a loop going over many $r$'s and $k$'s and check if the corresponding $n$ is an integer.

For example, in Matlab you could do:

```
for r = 1:r_end
  for k = 1:k_end 

    n = r + log(k^(k-r)) / (log(k)-log(r));
    if mod(n,1) == 0
      disp(['r = ', num2str(r), ' , k = ', num2str(k), ' , n = ', num2str(n)])
    end

  end
end
```

This gives many solutions, such as $[r,k,n] = [27,3,39]$, $[49,7,91]$ or $[9,81,153]$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $n,r,k$ be non negative integers such that $r,k\leq n$.

First of all $(r,k,n)=(0,0,n)$, where $n \neq 0$ is a trivial solution for $r^{n-r} = k^{n-k}$.

For further solutions, we have

$$\begin{align}
r^{n-r} & = k^{n-k} \\
(n-r) \cdot \ln r & = (n-k) \cdot \ln k \\
n & = {\frac{r\ln r - k\ln k}{\ln  r - \ln k}}.
\end{align}$$

Now to provide, that $n$ is an integer let $a$ be a nonnegative integer, and take $k=r^a$. If $a=1$, then $r=k$ and then if $r=k=0$, then $n\neq r$, but else $n$ could be anything. If $a \neq 1$, then

$$n = \frac{r-ar^a}{1-a},$$

which is an integer for appropriate $(r,a)$ pairs. I don't know a condition for this.

So I think there are infinitly many solutions in the form
$$(r,k,n) = \left(r,r^a,\frac{r-ar^a}{1-a} \right).$$

If you can find such condition for $n$, that when is it integer, then you could find all solutions.

Examples: $(2,4,6), (2,8,11), (3,9,15), (3,27,39), (3,81,107), (3,243,303) (4,16,28), (4,64,94), (4,256,340), (4,1024,1279), (5,25,45), \ \dots$

Comment: If you let $a=b+1$, the solutions can be written as $$(r,k,n)=\left(r,r^{b+1},r^{b+1}+{r(r^b-1)\over b}\right)$$ from which it's clear that you have infinitely many solutions with $r\equiv0$ mod $b$ and infinitely many more with $r\equiv1$ mod $b$.